# Select and Insert in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Table: students

```
studentid | rollNo | name
```

Table: classRecord

```
recordId | studentId | isPresent
```

students.studentid is the foreign key for classRecord.studentId

I have the value of the rollNo from the students table and also whether he was present in class or not and I want to get the studentid from the students table and insert it into classRecord. I want to first get the value of studentid for a rollNo and then Insert this value of studentid into classRecord table.

Comment: You can use the PHP Method to get an associative array?  I'm a bit confused as to what your question title has to do with the body

Comment: How the question is related to the title?

Comment: Sorry.  Forgot to change the title. It is based only on pure sql

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: @r0xette  Updated the question. Please check again

Comment: @DanBracuk how can it be done in a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a subquery to select the student ID from the student table, and insert it into the classRecord table:

```
INSERT INTO classRecord (studentId, isPresent)
    SELECT student.studentId, <is_present_value> 
    FROM student 
    WHERE student.rollNo = <rollNo_value>;
```

Comment: Added some explanatory text.

Comment: Do you need to insert three column values into a table with three columns?  Or specify that you're skipping the `recordID` column by listing the other two: `INSERT INTO classRecord(studentId, isPresent) SELECT …`?

Comment: Oops. You are correct. I have modified this answer to reflect this.